# adding user to a mailchimp mailing-list using mailchimp-api plugin for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, mailchimp, mandrill

I am trying to use mailchimp-api for node.js to add a user emailId to a mailing-list. I wrote the following function.

```
subscribeEmail: function(listId, emailId) {
        var mcapi = require("mailchimp-api");
        mc = new mcapi.Mailchimp('api-key');
        console.log(emailId);
        mc.lists.subscribe({id: listId, email: [ {'email': emailId } ]}, function(data) {
                console.log("Successfully Subscribed");
            },
            function(error) {
                if (error.error) {
                    console.log(error.code + ": " + error.error);
                } else {
                    console.log('There was an error subscribing that user');
                }
            });
        }
```

I end-up receiving the following error,

```
-100: The email parameter should include an email, euid, or leid key
```

does any have any suggestions as to why. Any help will be appreciated. cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made a simple mistake.

This line:

```js
mc.lists.subscribe({id: listId, email: [ {'email': emailId } ]}, function(data) {
```

Should look like this:

```js
mc.lists.subscribe({id: listId, email: {'email': emailId }}, function(data) {
```

**Explanation:**
You are passing an object `[ {'email': emailId } ]` to the function but it is expecting a value: `{'email': emailId }`

Example code from the github express [example app](https://github.com/mailchimp/mcapi2-node-examples/blob/master/express/routes/lists.js):

```
 mc.lists.subscribe({
       id: req.params.id,
       email: {
         email: req.body.email
       }
     }, function(data) {
       req.session.success_flash = 'User subscribed successfully! Look for the confirmation email.';
       res.redirect('/lists/' + req.params.id);
     }
```